# Django: Different User models with custom fields

Tags: django, django-models

I'm working on a new project and I'm facing some doubts planning the User model.

I need two User types:

- Client: The client will be able to buy stuff
- Shopper: The shop client will be able to sell the stuff

This models will share some basic data like:

- Address
- Phone
- NIF
- and some others...

But each user type will also have custom fields.

I'm planning about creating a new model **Profile** with the shared fields, and then using heritage implement 2 submodels **ProfileClient** and **ProfileShop** with the custom fields.

I'm wondering if this is the best approach or there is some better way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess a user can be both Client and Shopper at the same time, is it? If so, I would suggest to create a **Profile** model, then **Client** and **Shopper** has a foreign key to link to **Profile**. In this approach, you don't need to save same profile info twice.

Answer (score 1):

Best approach is subjective, but to support more profile types in the future without adding a subclass of the Profile model each time , you could have a JSONField on the Profile model which contains arbitrary data for the Profile type.

```
class SharedProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    address = models.CharField(#..)
    phone = models.CharField(#...) # or phone field, whatever
    # optionally add a preferred profile, or current profile data , and then add properties on the model that get the attributes from the related Profile entry.
    current_profile = models.ForeignKey('foo.models.Profile')

class Profile(models.Model):
    shared_profile = models.ForeignKey(SharedProfile)
    profile_type = models.CharField(choices=PROFILE_CHOICES)
    profile_data = JSONField() # whatever JSONField package you are using
```